# Calculate $E(f|\mathcal{F})$

Tags: probability, expected-value

How to calculate conditional expected value $E(f|\mathcal{F})$ when: $\Omega=[0,1] \times [0,1]$, $f(x,y)=x^2y$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is the sigma body generated by $y$. Which theorem/formula we need to use here?

Comment: Do I understand correctly? In other words, you have independent random variables $X,Y$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and you want to find $\mathbb E[f(X,Y)| \sigma(Y)]$, yes?

Comment: If $\sigma(y) = \sigma(Y)$ then yes. I'm not sure what it means "sigma body generated by y"...

Comment: Sigma body/field generated by some random variable is just $\sigma(Y) = \{Y^{-1}[B] : B \in \mathcal B([0,1])\}$ (that is, we look at all preimages under $Y$ of all borel sets)

Comment: Is the measure on $[0,1]$  the uniform measure?, or any other measure. That will determine the answer: $E[X^2Y|\sigma(Y)]=Y \,E[X^2|\sigma(Y)]$

Comment: There is a theorem saying that we can pull measurable variables out of conditional expectation. Namely $\mathbb E[U \cdot V | \mathcal G] = V\mathbb E[U | \mathcal G]$ when $V$ is $\mathcal G$ measurable. Using this we get $\mathbb E[f(X,Y)|\sigma(Y)] = Y\mathbb E[X^2 | \sigma(Y)]$ (and provided they're independent) the last one is just $Y\mathbb E[X^2] = \frac{Y}{3}$)

Comment: @OliverDiaz yes it is a Lebesgue measure on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$

Comment: @Mia: them, from my previous comment all you have to do is estimate $E[X^2|\sigma(Y)]$, but that should be easy since then for Lebesgue measure in the unit box $X$ and $Y$ are independent r.v. (think a little about this).